# Spotify - Search for an Artist

Tags: javascript, html, css, api, spotify

I've come across this demo http://jsfiddle.net/JMPerez/0u0v7e1b/
Which is to search for an artist using spotify API.
I've tried loads of attempts and cannot get it to work.
Any pointers on how this can work?

HTML code from demo:

```
<div class="container">
<h1>Search for an Artist</h1>
<p>Type an artist name and click on "Search". Then, click on any album from the results to play 30 seconds of its first track.</p>
<form id="search-form">
    <input type="text" id="query" value="" class="form-control" placeholder="Type an Artist Name"/>
    <input type="submit" id="search" class="btn btn-primary" value="Search" />
</form>
<div id="results"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason this code sample isn't working is because a token wasn't provided. If you try to access https://api.spotify.com/v1/search, then the site returns this:

```
{
  "error": {
    "status": 401,
    "message": "No token provided"
  }
}
```

You can attach the token in the headers as authorization, similar to this:

```
$.ajax({
   url: 'https://api.spotify.com/v1/search',
   headers: {
      'Authorization': 'Bearer <token>'
   },
   success: function (result) {
       // CallBack(result);
   },
});
```

To get a developer token, you can check Spotify's documentation: https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/general/guides/authorization-guide/

For more information on using Spotify's Web API, you can also check out their quick start guide: https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/web-api/quick-start/